# How would you instantiate linked struct objects recursively?

Tags: c++, pointers, nodes

> Suppose you have a structure (lets call it Node) containing a string Content and a vector(Node*) Children.
>
> Suppose a child string is a function of the parent string, so you need to use a recursive method to generate and link child Nodes to parent Nodes.

What would be an effective method of doing so? My current approach is:

```
void Node::branch(vector<vector<Node>> &generations) {
    string child;                                       //this will be the content of the child Node
    int generation_i = 0                                //index of vector in which child Node will be stored (this vector is one of the 'generations' in generations)
    child = make_substring(content);                    //returns a child string based on content
    generations[generation_i].emplace_back(child);      //make a child Node in generation
    child.branch(generations);                          //recursion
    adopt(generations[generation_i][generations[generation_i].size() - 1]);     //store (address of child Node) in children
```

However, when I execute that code, all of the children of a node have the same content and address, suggesting that `adopt()` is appending the passed address and also replacing every address already present with the one passed into it.

```
void Node::adopt(Node child) { children.push_back(&child); }//append [address of child] to children [vector of pointers to children]
```

Comment: In the body of adopt, you are taking the address of a local variable (the argument, passed in by value, goes out of scope after). You might want to make it `void Node::adopt(Node& child) { ... }` . Although, still in that case, storing the pointer instead of the object itself is probably not a good idea

Comment: Unless you pre-allocate all of the memory for all possible nodes up front, a linked list doesn't work very well without dynamically allocating every node, which this code is not doing. And `vector<Node>` is not a good container for linked lists, because as soon as the vector has to resize its `capacity()`, pointers to its elements get invalidated. Is there a reason why you are not using `std::list` for the linked list?

Comment: You're appending the address of the local variable `child` which then immediately goes out of scope - which is undefined behavior if you ever dereference that pointer afterwards.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Frankly I'm using vectors because I'm inexperienced with C++ and vectors are the only data structure I knew besides arrays, but reading up on lists I can see what you mean about pointer invalidation.

Comment: @Kama `std::list` is C++'s standard container for double-linked lists (there is also `std::forward_list` for single-linked lists).